# How is the None keyword argument converted into a int datatype?

Tags: python, nonetype

Disclaimer: This is not my code. It originated from [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) created by Dr. John Zelle.

Where is `rate` declared as a number? I understand that it is a keyword argument of type `None`, but how is this `pauselength = 1/rate-(now-_update_lasttime)` valid? To my knowledge, this is saying that `1` is divisible by `None`.

```py
import time, os, sys

try:  # import as appropriate for 2.x vs. 3.x
   import tkinter as tk
except:
   import Tkinter as tk

# global variables and functions

_root = tk.Tk()
_root.withdraw()

_update_lasttime = time.time()

def update(rate=None):
    global _update_lasttime
    if rate:
        now = time.time()
        pauseLength = 1/rate-(now-_update_lasttime)
        if pauseLength > 0:
            time.sleep(pauseLength)
            _update_lasttime = now + pauseLength
        else:
            _update_lasttime = now

    _root.update()
```

A simple experiment:

```py
a = None
b = 1
print(b/a)
```

Reveals the following error (Which makes complete sense):

```py
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any conflict here. `pauseLength = 1/rate-(now-_update_lasttime)` is never executed when `rate=None`, because of the guard statement a few lines above: `if rate:`

Comment: rate is not "of type None", it has a default value of None.

Answer (score 1):

If `rate` is `None`, the conditional `if rate:` is false, so none of the code in the following block (including the problematic division) runs. The only code which runs in that situation is `_root.update()`.

Comment: OH! Thank you! I thought that `if rate:` was `True`. That makes a lot of sense then!